# Regex expression to extract dates in text?

Tags: regex

I have these following text.Few are selected and few are not.

Any 9/20/1993     [Selected]

Or 9/20/93       [Selected]

09.20.1993     [Selected]

09/20/1993           [Selected]

93/09/20            [Selected]

Wednesday 09/20/93 and done on 9/20/1993 12:00 AM   [Not selected][In between text]

1993 - 09 - 20           [Not selected][white spaces not ignored]

9/20/1993 12:00 AM        [Not selected]

Now I am using this: ([0-9]{1,4}[\s*(/?-?.?\)?\s*][0-9]{1,4}[\s*(/?-?.?\)?\s*][0-9]{1,4})$

How to select pattern in between and ignore white spaces?

Note:  [] I put have reasons in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me exactly.

(?i)([0-9]{1,4}[( /?-?.?\?)]{1,}[0-9]{1,4}[( /?-?.?\?)]{1,}[0-9]{1,4})

Here is the working example: https://regex101.com/r/aU9jH6/1

Modifying @Toto's expression: https://regex101.com/r/nB4bU2/1

Comment: This regex matches: `0??(((???)))???0;--..().??()?????0123456789`, I don't think this is what you want. Did you try the one I've given? What's the matter with it?

Comment: Yes it will. I am trying to extract date from text. So I will not be sure in what format I will get the date. I mean there could be multiple spaces between day and month or year. Like "12 ,??-- 07--------    1993" or any but trying to get all texts that will have three set of digits in sequence without any text in between. And I am using other regex expression for selecting dates in full format like month name in it.

Comment: Yours also works fine but it will not select if date i get is in this format "93 -- 09 - 20". So i added this change to yours regular expression. Instead of this "\s*[\/.-]?" I am using this "[( /?-?.?\?)]{1,}" to make it little more flexible. And I found there are many formats that people use to represent date which make it more complex. Just trying to get most suitable types and then process them to extract day,month,year and convert into DateTime object in c#.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `\s*` outside of the character class and use word boundaries (`\b`):

```
\b(\d{1,2}\s*[/.-]?\s*\d{1,2}\s*[/.-]?\d{1,4})\b
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I modified it little bit so that it will not ignore white spaces. [Click to see the working model](https://regex101.com/r/nB4bU2/1)